# "No Message provided" when attempting to read a parameter from a dictionary javascript

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, parse-platform

My goal is to get the parameters from the user objects returned from my query. Here is the query:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userData", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("PushUser");

    query.equalTo("userID", request.params.adnUserID);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            response.success(results);
        },
        error: function(){
            response.error("user lookup failed")
        }
    });
});
```

When I print the response `print r.text`:

```
{"result":[{"userID":"5253","deviceToken":"1234","pushCode":"a1m1s1r1f1p0","objectId":"bZ3HWMWfVj","createdAt":"2014-06-24T14:01:54.484Z","updatedAt":"2014-06-24T14:02:20.007Z","__type":"Object","className":"PushUser"},
           {"userID":"5253","deviceToken":"5678","pushCode":"a0m0s0r0f0p0","objectId":"SV73ZOSzNC","createdAt":"2014-06-24T13:37:25.369Z","updatedAt":"2014-06-24T13:47:50.689Z","__type":"Object","className":"PushUser"}]}
```

Then when I try modify my query code to return a parameter, say the deviceToken, I get `No Message provided` spit into the console.log. This is how I attempt to access the parameter:

```
var token = results[0].deviceToken;
```

However, when I run the same code (copied directly from the log) in JSFiddle, it works perfectly;

Does anyone have any idea what the heck is going on?

Comment: Try `var token = results.result[0].deviceToken`, by the looks of the console.log, you're getting an object `results` that has the property `result` which contains the array of objects containing `userID`, etc

Comment: @Kodlee Yin it throws an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(typeof results)`?

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was Parse was returning objects that printed to the console like they were dictionaries. In reality though, they were container object (I guess).

To access the properties:

```
var name = user.get('name');
```

I'm out of my depth here. I'm a new Objective-c developer, I'm pampered by an inline debugger and code completion.

Comment: You're correct. When working with Cloud Code and the JavaScript SDK, queries return an array of Parse.Object. Here's the relevant doc for that "class."  http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html